# SQL Loop Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

So here is the deal. I got what we call "ProjectIDs" which is a field in our database (Primary Key) we have 2 fields that need to be updated based on information that is within the project IDs. For example:

I might have a project ID

```
00068:
```

This projectID will not have what we call "Phases"... but I might have another Project that has "phases" which would have multiple records (i.e all separate jobs) but tied together by a diff fields.

```
0174:
0174-A-SEG-64:
0174-A-SEG-86:
0174-A-DEF-64:
0174-A-DEF-86:
```

So for example: `0174-A-SEG-64`, would be tied to `0174-A-SEG`:  2 fields would get updated for the record of `0174-A-SEG-64`.

```
ProjectIsPhase = -1 and ParentProjectID = 0174-A-SEG:
```

So the tricky part comes into play. Some of the "main" jobs like 0174-A-SEG: might not exist. So they would have to be created on the fly. Ideally as you can see from the example projects given 0174-A: does not exist neither does 0174-A-SEG: or 0174-A-DEF: So in the end the project structure needs to look as the following:

```
ProjectID           ProjectIsPhase               Parent ProjectID
0174: 
0174-A:             -1                           0174:
0174-A-SEG:         -1                           0174-A:
0174-A-DEF:         -1                           0174-A:
0174-A-SEG-64:      -1                           0174-A-SEG:
```

So when it ends up in a tree view it looks like the following

```
0174:
  0174-A:
    0174-A-SEG:
       0174-A-SEG-64:
    0174-A-DEF:
```

This all needs to be done via SQL or T-SQL

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  How to create the parent records?

Comment: Your tree is missing a few things, the DEF-86 at least

Comment: At least indicate where the starting point of all this is - is it a stored proc that takes just a project REF `0174-A-SEG-64` and some other columns, that creates the parent projects as required, including `0174`?

Comment: Yes for example it needs to update the current record it is on with the prior information (such as if it sees the record) 0174-A-SEG-64: then it would say ok Set the Project as Phase because this project has a - and Set the parent ProjectID = 0174-A-SEG: (Although 0174-A-SEG might not exist) which I would need to create it, so I guess the generation of the parent projectID as a record could be done in a second pass by comparing what the table already has vs what it does not based on a distinct(parentprojectID) and create them from that.

Comment: Did this post go dead that quick? anyone able to help with this?

Comment: You need to rewrite your question. Explain the input(s) and desired output(s). You state certain records do not exist, but do make make clear what records are present at the time you want to execute an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve with `ProjectIsPhase`, but I suspect that's the trivial part of your problem.

Given a `ProjectID`, you can derive the `ParentProjectID` as follows: (might need a few +-1 tweaks to account for the separator.)

```
LEFT(ProjectID, LEN(ProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ProjectID))
```

So then insert parent projects that don't exist:

```
INSERT INTO Projects(ProjectID)
SELECT  LEFT(ProjectID, LEN(ProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ProjectID))
FROM    Projects p
WHERE   LEFT(ProjectID, LEN(ProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ProjectID)) 
        NOT IN (
        SELECT  ProjectID
        FROM    Projects
        )
-- You might need to double-check the best condition to not insert a "parent" for a root project
AND     LEFT(ProjectID, LEN(ProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ProjectID)) <> ''
```

You can run the above until no more parents are missing. You could also use a `WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0` loop.

Once all parent projects have been inserted, you can update the ParentProjectID of all projects simultaneously.

```
UPDATE  Projects
SET ParentProjectID = LEFT(ProjectID, LEN(ProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ProjectID))
```

---

**EDIT**
After reading comments, it looks like you want to do this for a particular project.
Then tweaking the above and using local variables should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @CurrentProjectID varchar, 
        @ParentProjectID varchar
SET @CurrentProjectID = @InputProjectID
SET @ParentProjectID = LEFT(@CurrentProjectID, LEN(@CurrentProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@CurrentProjectID))

WHILE @ParentProjectID <> ''
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Projects
    WHERE   ProjectID = @ParentProjectID
  )
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectID)
    VALUES (@ParentProjectID)
  END
  UPDATE  Projects
  SET     ParentProjectID = @ParentProjectID
  WHERE   ProjectID = @CurrentProjectID
    SET @CurrentProjectID = @ParentProjectID
    SET @ParentProjectID = LEFT(@CurrentProjectID, LEN(@CurrentProjectID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@CurrentProjectID))
END
```

You also have the option to ensure you're allowing recursive calls in your stored procs, and have the stored proc call itself with the current ProjectID's parent.

Comment: PS: By the way, the complications here point to some design problems: 1) The hierarchy is duplicated: in the hyphen separated IDs and in `ParentProjectID`. 2) The names at each level of the hierarchy are duplicated. 3) There are data-integrity violations because projects exist without their parents. (Is this intentional?)  I acknowledge SQL doesn't generally work well with hierarchical data, and this tends to result in cludgy workarounds. But perhaps some of the complication could be eased by design changes? Of course this depends on the needs of other parts of your system.